# Command not found

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

Hi i'm going to create one script (.sh or .command) my Script is

```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo Build Begin
  'xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 5s (8.3 Simulator)"'
```

i got error,

```
  Last login: Mon Mar 21 15:48:29 on ttys000
  MacBook-Pro:~ user$ /Users/user/CommandWorld.command ; exit;
  Build Begin
  /Users/user/CommandWorld.command: line 3: xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 5s (8.3 Simulator)": command not found
  logout

  [Process completed]
```

If i run command "xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 5s (8.3 Simulator)"" as it is on terminal then its worked ... but why it not in script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting the whole command inside single quotes, you make the shell assume it is a single word ; it then expects to find a command that match it, rather than the command `xcrun`. Remove the single quotes and you should be alright.

The double quotes are here for the same purpose (and should not be removed) : to pass "iPhone 5s (8.3 Simulator)" as a single word rather than a list of words (`iPhone`, `5s`, `(8.3` and `Simulator)`).